# Suddenly get do/catch error

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

I've been running this code for quite sometime however suddenly it throws error below, how come i suddenly get this without editing the code? and what am i doing wrong in my do/catch statement?

```
func addInput(device: AVCaptureDevice) {

    do {
        captureSession.addInput(try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))

    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

**error**

```
Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive
```

Comment: You did not show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the possibility of a `catch` with or without  `error`. Just add a new catch statement.

```
do              { /* try something */ }
catch let error { print((error as NSError)) }
catch           { print("No error") }
```

If you use the version in the second line you might not need the third line.